# Maximum allowed number of characters FTP command prompt

Tags: command-line, ftp, windows-10, windows-server-2012-r2

After updating our FTP server to Windows 2012R2 we encountered some issues with password lengths. The simplest example is:
- open a command prompt
- ftp 
- type username
- type password

When the password is 30 characters or less, there is no issue. When the password is 31 characters or more, the login fails:

> 530 User cannot log in.
>   Login failed.
>   ftp> Invalid command.

It looks like the command prompt is parsing the password as two lines. No strange characters are in the password.

Could anyone please confirm changes to FTP in Windows 2012R2 or Windows 10 FTP client for example? I'm at a loss... I really do not wish to reduce the number of characters in the password to 30.

Comment: Martin Prikyl: I've tested it and came to the conclusion that the maximum password length is 32 characters, where I'm certain that this wasn't the case a little while back. We have set up an API and subsequent FTP connection using a 36-character password and this functioned fine up until around april 10th 2017.

I also tried to push the commands via an external file (ftp -s:<filename>), and this clearly shows that only 32 characters of the 36 are sent. The leftover 4 characters result in some form of unknown command error.